# Boost.Python: Module inside module

Tags: c++, boost-python

Using Boost.Python, how can I define a module inside another (or rather, as if it were located in a folder)?

Comment: I don't have time for a proper write up but I have a link: ( http://goo.gl/NXsjf ) with what you need. Feel free to do a proper writeup if you get around to it first.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing it into a subfolder? seriously, I think this is how Python manages package hierarchies and makes lookups upon imports. See the official documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

To your question: I haven't stumbled upon the matter of declaring modules inside modules. I don't think this is possible with Boost.Python, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Placing it in a subfolder isn't an option because I'm embedding Python, I'm not extending it.

Comment: Your objection doesn't make sense, unless I misunderstand. If you embed python, but write module in `boost::python`, then you are extending the (embedded) python with your new module.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
using namespace boost::python;
object moduleA=import("moduleA");
object moduleB=import("moduleB");
moduleA.attr("moduleB")=moduleB;
```

if you really need it in c++. Kind reader can write the same in python as an exercise ;-)